# Nginx not preserving domain name for wordpress proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, mac-osx, wordpress, proxypass

In my `/etc/hosts` file I added an alias to localhost like this:
`127.0.0.1    example.local`

My wordpress server is hosted on port 8000 so I use `proxy_pass`:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name example.local;

   root /Users/akashagarwal/Downloads/wordpress;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
   }
}
```

There are two problems that I'm facing.
1. Upon opening `http://example.local` in my browser, the address bar gets appended with `:8000`.
2. Upon clicking a link, the host name gets changed to `localhost:8000`.
What am I doing wrong here?

Running `nginx version: nginx/1.10.3` on `macOS Sierra 10.12.1`.
TIA

Comment: You need to fix your web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem definitely isn't nginx: your application is rewriting client accesses to the hostname it knows of. Look for nginx logs, I'ld bet there's a few 30x-code logs, redirecting you somehow, ...

Your config refers to Wordpress, I'ld wild-guess that you should add to your `wp-config.php` [something like](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL):

```
define('WPSITEURL','http://example.local/');
define('WPHOME','http://example.local/');
```